# Delete rows from zoo-object based on conditions

Tags: r, zoo

I merged 2 different (irregular) time series (*merge.zoo()* ). Looks like:

```
                     quir   schme 
2006-01-01 01:15:00 725.24   4.64
2006-01-01 01:30:00 725.24   4.64
2006-01-01 01:45:00      0   4.64
2006-01-01 02:00:00 725.24   4.64
```

I want to delete all rows where 0 values appear, to receive:

```
                    quir   schme 
2006-01-01 01:15:00 725.24   4.64
2006-01-01 01:30:00 725.24   4.64
2006-01-01 02:00:00 725.24   4.64
```

I didn't find a proper way to to this for zoo-objects so I used the very unelegant way to export the data to a *.csv and treat the rows upon re-import.
Anyone who is willing to share a more elegant way?

Best regards
Jochen

Answer (score 2):

You can use `subset` or `[`

```
library(zoo) 
subset(z1, quir!=0)
#                      quir schme
#2006-01-01 01:15:00 725.24  4.64
#2006-01-01 01:30:00 725.24  4.64
#2006-01-01 02:00:00 725.24  4.64
```

If you need to remove rows if there are `0` values in any of the columns

```
z1[!rowSums(z1==0),]
#                      quir schme
#2006-01-01 01:15:00 725.24  4.64
#2006-01-01 01:30:00 725.24  4.64
#2006-01-01 02:00:00 725.24  4.64
```

Or as @G.Grothendieck mentioned in the comments, we can loop over the rows with `apply` and get the logical index with `all` or `any`.  Here, `!` indicates negation. `!!` double negation (`z1!=0` and `!!z1` are the same).

```
 z1[apply(z1 != 0, 1, all), ]
 z1[apply(!!z1, 1, all), ]
 z1[!apply(z1 == 0, 1, any), ]
```

#### data

```
z1 <- structure(c(725.24, 725.24, 0, 725.24, 4.64, 4.64, 4.64, 4.64
), .Dim = c(4L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("quir", "schme"
)), index = structure(c(1136096100, 1136097000, 1136097900, 1136098800
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), class = "zoo")
```

Comment: These also work: `z1[apply(z1 != 0, 1, all), ]`, `z1[apply(!!z1, 1, all), ]`, 
`z1[!apply(z1 == 0, 1, any), ]` .

Comment: @G.Grothendieck you should write them as answer

Comment: These don't seem different enough from the current answer to warrant a completely new answer.